# Only one request is effective when parallelly send requests to insert permissions

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm having problem trying to send a batch of permission insert requests, here are the steps:

1. Upload a small txt file with DriveService.Files.Insert
2. Create 2 parallel requests to add permissions (DriveService.Permissions.Insert) for two different users, I'm getting success responses for both requests with permission IDs
3. Delegate the two users' account and use DriveService.Files.Get to get the file

I expected the two users' account will have access to the uploaded file, but I'm getting 404 error for one of them. I suppose only one of the request is effective.

Permissions.List only returns 2 permissions, one for owner, one for one of the two users.
In the Web UI there are only two users listed, the owner and one of the two users.

Is it a bug in the drive service?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't you receive a 403 error if have not the sufficient rights the read the file?

Comment: The problem is from one of the users' account I can't even find the file.

Comment: Have you tried DriveService.Permissions.List or else the Web UI to see what the ACLs look like after the parallel insert?

Comment: In the Web UI, there is only one user listed, the other one is missing.